# SQL - User Zebra Table - are two users following each other?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called `user_zebra`:

[image: Click here to see the table]

This table is used to store friendships between two members on my site - the user_id is whoever sent the friend request and the member_id is the person whom they tried to add.  The date is self-explanatory.

When the other user responds yes to the friend request, another entry is added but with the user_id and the member_id flipped.  Only when there is an entry for both sides are you considered friends... otherwise you are just following that user.

What I need to know is if there is SQL code that can return the user_id and member_id only if there is another entry with these values flipped.  Is this possible?  Or is there an easier way?

I hope I made this clear and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  One method is `exists`:

```
select user_id, member_id
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.member_id and t2.member_id = t.user_id
             );
```

MySQL also supports the very convenient `IN`-with-tuples syntax:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.user_id, t.member_id) in (select t2.member_id, t2.user_id from t t2);
```

In both of these, you might want to add `where user_id < member_id` to avoid duplicates in the result set.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot tomorrow and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a self join here:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.member_id
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.member_id AND t1.member_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id <= t1.member_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic of the above query is to attempt to match each record with its counterpart where the `user_id` and `member_id` have swapped positions.  The `WHERE` clause restricts to relationships where the `user_id` is less than or equal to the `member_id`.  You never told us which one of the pairs you want to report; this is one way to do it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Uh... [no it wouldn't](http://rextester.com/XUKU60667).

Comment: never mind i readed the question and understanded from the question the topicstarter needed both relations (records)..